# How to retrieve an attribute from a list of instances properly

Tags: python, object, attributes, instance

I am unsure how to correctly get the attribute from a list of instances. Sorry if this seems simple, I am only a beginner.

```
class Clown:
    def __init__(self,name,hours,job):
        self.name = name
        self.hours = hours
        self.job = job
        
    def get_job(self):
        return self.job
    
    def change_job(self, new_job):
        self.job = new_job
        

list_of_clowns = [Clown("Tom",3,"puppets"), Clown("Jeff",1,"ballon animals")]

clown1 = Clown("Andy",4,"unicycle")


print(list_of_clowns[0].get_job) #problem

print(clown1.get_job()) #this works and prints "unicycle"
```

When I use
`print(list_of_clowns[0].get_job)`
it gives
`<bound method Clown.get_job of <__main__.Clown object at 0x000001CE928DE20>>`
when I want
`puppets`

Comment: You can see the difference between the two print lines, lack of parentheses in the method on the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By printing `list_of_clowns[0].get_job` you're printing the definition of the method `def get_job(self):`.

Changing it to `list_of_clowns[0].get_job()` (note the parentheses), you will execute the method that than will return `puppets`.